# Deploy a WCF service on a non sharepoint Environemnt

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service that uses the DLL : `Microsoft.Sharepoint`

When I deployed it to the server that does not have SharePoint installed on it then I got the below error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: What are you trying to do in this web service? There is a good chance that even with those DLLs, your application won't work. Microsoft.SharePoint assemblies require to be executed on the SharePoint server (that's why it's called Server Side Object Model). Cinsider using CSOM instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to get a lot of not so great answers on this question:

You can not use the Server Object Model outside of the SharePoint farm. This means that you can not use the `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`.

Instead you need to use the Client Object Model (CSOM). So you need to convert your code (rewrite it) to CSOM and instead of the  `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`, reference the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`

Comment: Thanks for your answer . for solving my issue I make a another web service that has the original one as a client and call the functions . This does not require any SharePoint dependencies

Answer (score -2):

In you WCF service project in Visual Studio, click expand `References` in the project select the reference to Microsoft.SharePoint and open the `Properties` dialog and on the property `Copy Local` select `True`.

Then the DLL will be included in the project when being built.

Comment: To not much help if the wcf is not run on the SharePoint servers. In this situation we need to use the Client dlls